# Find combinations of all brackets in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to write a simple code for generating all combinations of brackets..But am stuck with a simple type error.

```
balancedParens :: Int -> [String]
balancedParens n
            | n==0 = []
            | otherwise = placeParens 0 1 0 n [""]
          where placeParens x lc rc n mlist
                                | lc == n = mlist
                                | rc == n = mlist
                                | lc < n = placeParens (x+1) (lc+1) rc n ((mlist !! x) ++ "L")
                                | rc < n = placeParens (x+1) lc (rc+1) n ((mlist !! x) ++ "R")
```

There are lots of errors but most prominent is

```
Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: [[Char]]
  Actual type: [Char]
In the first argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘mlist’
In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(mlist !! x)’
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

((mlist !! x) ++ "L") is a list so why the type error? How come it is matching [Char]?

Comment: `mlist` is a list of strings, `mlist!!x` is a string, `(mlist!!x)++"L"` is also a string.

Comment: you need list of Strings, you have a String which is a list or [Char]

Comment: Do you mean a program like [this](http://ideone.com/UMKhiF)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem statement

Let's define what a balanced string is, inductively:

- `""` is balanced
- if `x` and `y` are balanced, `"(" ++ x ++ ")" ++ y` is balanced

All the balanced strings can be constructed using the above rules.

## The finite case

We want to enumerate all the balanced strings having exactly `n` parentheses. We follow the inductive rules above.

```
paren :: Int -> [String]
paren 0 = [""]
paren n = [ "(" ++ x ++ ")" ++ y
          | m <- [0..n-1] , x <- paren m , y <- paren (n-1-m) ]
```

In the second rule, we divide the remaining `n-1` parentheses in two parts, in any possible way. The first part is made of `m` parentheses, with `0 <= m <= n-1`. The second therefore
is made of `(n-1)-m` parentheses.

## The infinite case

Let's raise the bar. We don't want just the combinations for a specific `n`, we want an exhaustive list comprising all of them. We might `concat $ map paren [0..]` but that feels silly: why should we partition the set over the number of parentheses `n` when we are going to concatenate the results anyway?

Instead, let's directly enumerate all the infinite balanced strings. 
This is a job for the [Omega](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html) monad. We just need to use the inductive rules, once again:

```
import Control.Monad.Omega

allParen :: Omega String
allParen = return ""
       <|> (\x y -> "(" ++ x ++ ")" ++ y) <$> allParen <*> allParen
```

This is even simpler than `paren` since we never need to count the number of parentheses.

A quick test in GHCi:

```
> take 20 $ runOmega allParen
["","()","()()","(())","()()()","(())()","(()())","()(())","(())()()","(()())()","((()))","()()()()","(())(())","(()())()()","((()))()","(()()())","()(())()","(())()()()","(()())(())","((()))()()"]
```

Comment: The omega version doesn't compute the strings in order of increasing length. Why?

Comment: @n.m. Omega makes no such guarantees: it applies a dovetailing/diagonalization function to reduce all the infinite combinations to a single list. The order in which each combination appears in the final list has no significant property. In other words, `join` has roughly the type `[[a]] -> [a]` but is more involved than `concat`, and acts as a fair scheduler among infinitely many threads, each one producing a list `[a]`.

Comment: @n.m. I realized that I pasted the output for a different code of mine. Now I edited with the actual one.

Comment: I just tried to compare the performance of the omega version and my simple memoizing version [here](http://ideone.com/UMKhiF), and realized the comparison is not fair because they don't compute the result in the same order.

Comment: @n.m. I like that your solution does not use naturals, and is memoized (unlike mine). It also produces the results in a predictable order. You could add some comment to it and post it here as an answer.