# Generic algorithm to enumerate sum and product types on Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, generic-programming

Some time ago, I've asked [how to map back and forth from godel numbers to terms of a context-free language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923229/is-there-a-fast-algorithm-to-determine-the-godel-number-of-a-term-of-a-context-f). While the answer solved the issue specificaly, I'm having trouble in actually programming it generically. So, this question is more generic: given a recursive algebraic data type with terminals, sums and products - such as

```
data Term = Prod Term Term | SumL Term | SumR Term | AtomA | AtomB
```

what is an algorithm that will map a term of this type to its godel number, and its inverse?

Edit: for example:

```
data Foo = A | B Foo | C Foo deriving Show

to :: Foo -> Int
to A = 1
to (B x) = to x * 2
to (C x) = to x * 2 + 1

from :: Int -> Foo
from 1 = A
from n = case mod n 2 of
    0 -> B (from (div n 2))
    1 -> C (from (div n 2))
```

Here, `to` and `from` do what I want for `Foo`. I'm just asking for a systematic way to derive those functions for any datatype.

Comment: Does [How to enumerate a recursive datatype in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515191/how-to-enumerate-a-recursive-datatype-in-haskell) answer your question?

Comment: If you want an explicit version of the bijection, you can mechanically build one from the bijections `encodeTimes :: Integer->Integer->Integer` (dovetailing) and `encodePlus :: Either Integer Integer -> Integer` (interleaving) and little else. You apply these following the definition of your recursive type.

Comment: You can also use [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27809179/3234959) to enumerate a type using list comprehensions.

Comment: @chi this question is mine too - notice the generic answer isn't an algorithm to map back and forth from godel numberings - it goes one way, so it is not what I'm asking for. (You could do it by enumerating and then finding the element on the list, but that'd be unpractical.)

Comment: What I'm really asking for is a generic, systematic way to derive `fromGodel : Int → Type` and `toGodel : Type → Int`, [like this one](http://lpaste.net/125863).

Comment: You cannot encode lazy infinite values like `let x = 1:x in x`.

Comment: @n.m. A suitably lazy natural number type might be able to encode such values.

Comment: @DanielWagner There are more infinite lists than natural numbers...

Comment: @n.m. There are the same number of computable infinite lists as there are computable natural numbers.

Comment: @DanielWagner that's right, now can we have a method to skip non-computable ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid dealing with a particular Goedel numbering, let's define a class that'll abstract the necessary operations (with some imports we'll need later):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, DefaultSignatures, FlexibleContexts, DeriveGeneric #-}
import Control.Applicative
import GHC.Generics
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Gen

class GodelNum a where
    fromInt :: Integer -> a
    toInt :: a -> Maybe Integer
    encode :: [a] -> a
    decode :: a -> [a]
```

So we can inject natural numbers and encode sequences. Let's further create a canonical instance of this class that'll use throughout the code, which does no real Goedel encoding, just constructs a tree of terms.

```
data TermNum = Value Integer | Complex [TermNum]
  deriving (Show)

instance GodelNum TermNum where
    fromInt = Value
    toInt (Value x) = Just x
    toInt _         = Nothing
    encode = Complex
    decode (Complex xs) = xs
    decode _            = []
```

For real encoding we'd use another implementation that'd use just one `Integer`, something like `newtype SomeGoedelNumbering = SGN Integer`.

Let's further create a class for types that we can encode/decode:

```
class GNum a where
    gto :: (GodelNum g) => a -> g
    gfrom :: (GodelNum g) => g -> Maybe a

    default gto :: (Generic a, GodelNum g, GGNum (Rep a)) => a -> g
    gto = ggto . from
    default gfrom :: (Generic a, GodelNum g, GGNum (Rep a)) => g -> Maybe a
    gfrom = liftA to . ggfrom
```

The last four lines define a generic implementation of `gto` and `gfrom` using GHC [Generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) and `DefaultSignatures`. The class `GGNum` that they use is a helper class which we'll use to define encoding for the atomic ADT operations - products, sums, etc.:

```
class GGNum f where
    ggto :: (GodelNum g) => f a -> g
    ggfrom :: (GodelNum g) => g -> Maybe (f a)

-- no-arg constructors
instance GGNum U1 where
    ggto U1 = encode []
    ggfrom _ = Just U1

-- products
instance (GGNum a, GGNum b) => GGNum (a :*: b) where
    ggto (a :*: b) = encode [ggto a, ggto b]
    ggfrom e | [x, y] <- decode e    = liftA2 (:*:) (ggfrom x) (ggfrom y)
            | otherwise             = Nothing

-- sums
instance (GGNum a, GGNum b) => GGNum (a :+: b) where
    ggto (L1 x) = encode [fromInt 0, ggto x]
    ggto (R1 y) = encode [fromInt 1, ggto y]
    ggfrom e | [n, x] <- decode e = case toInt n of
                                    Just 0  -> L1 <$> ggfrom x
                                    Just 1  -> R1 <$> ggfrom x
                                    _       -> Nothing

-- metadata
instance (GGNum a) => GGNum (M1 i c a) where
    ggto (M1 x) = ggto x
    ggfrom e = M1 <$> ggfrom e

-- constants and recursion of kind *
instance (GNum a) => GGNum (K1 i a) where
    ggto (K1 x) = gto x
    ggfrom e = K1 <$> gfrom e
```

Having that, we can then define a data type like yours and just declare its `GNum` instance, everything else will be automatically derived.

```
data Term = Prod Term Term | SumL Term | SumR Term | AtomA | AtomB
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance GNum Term where
```

And just to be sure we've done everything right, let's use [QuickCheck](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/pbv/an-introduction-to-quickcheck-testing) to verify that our `gfrom` is an inverse of `gto`:

```
instance Arbitrary Term where
    arbitrary = oneof [ return AtomA
                      , return AtomB
                      , SumL <$> arbitrary
                      , SumR <$> arbitrary
                      , Prod <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary
                      ]

prop_enc_dec :: Term -> Property
prop_enc_dec x = Just x === gfrom (gto x :: TermNum)

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_enc_dec
```

**Notes**:

- The same thing could be accomplished using [Scrap Your Boilerplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb), perhaps more efficiently, as it allows somewhat higher-level access - enumerating constructors and records, etc.
- See also paper [Efficient Bijective G¨odel Numberings for Term Algebras](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~tarau/research/bijectiveNSF/cgoedel.pdf) (I haven't read the paper yet, but seems related).

Comment: How do we know `gto` is dense, i.e. its image on `SomeGoedelNumbering` is all the natural numbers?

Comment: @DanielWagner We don't, I didn't aim for that.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, I decided to try the approach in the link you posted, and didn't get stuck anywhere. So here's my code, with no commentary (the explanation is the same as the last time). First, code stolen from the other answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Universe.Helpers

type Nat = Integer
class Godel a where
    to   :: a -> Nat
    from :: Nat -> a

instance Godel Nat where to = id; from = id

instance (Godel a, Godel b) => Godel (a, b) where
    to (m_, n_) = (m + n) * (m + n + 1) `quot` 2 + m where
        m = to m_
        n = to n_
    from p = (from m, from n) where
        isqrt    = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
        base     = (isqrt (1 + 8 * p) - 1) `quot` 2
        triangle = base * (base + 1) `quot` 2
        m = p - triangle
        n = base - m
```

And the code specific to your new type:

```
data Term = Prod Term Term | SumL Term | SumR Term | AtomA | AtomB
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

ts = AtomA : AtomB : interleave [uncurry Prod <$> ts +*+ ts, SumL <$> ts, SumR <$> ts]

instance Godel Term where
    to AtomA = 0
    to AtomB = 1
    to (Prod t1 t2) = 2 + 0 + 3 * to (t1, t2)
    to (SumL t)     = 2 + 1 + 3 * to t
    to (SumR t)     = 2 + 2 + 3 * to t
    from 0 = AtomA
    from 1 = AtomB
    from n = case quotRem (n-2) 3 of
        (q, 0) -> uncurry Prod (from q)
        (q, 1) -> SumL (from q)
        (q, 2) -> SumR (from q)
```

The same ghci test as last time:

```
*Main> take 30 (map from [0..]) == take 30 ts
True
```

Comment: Ah, I see now I misunderstood the question. I will update with some comments about generic programming later.

Comment: I thank you for the answer which is correct and neat - but the thread is still not solved since that is not a generic algorithm, just one for my example datatype...

Comment: @Viclib I agree. I am still working on a generic version -- as you suggested, it is trickier than one might expect.

Comment: I guess it is. If you are doing this for this question, please, don't worry! But if you'll do it anyway, I guess it would be a great addition to Hackage.